# Issuse in playing Video in Javafx

Tags: javafx

I tried

```
public class Video3 extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
Group root = new Group();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 1024, Color.BLACK);
File file = new File("/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/VideoPaly/src/videopaly/vid.flv");
String path = file.toURI().toASCIIString(); 
URI uri = new URI(path);
root.getChildren().add(MediaViewBuilder.create().mediaPlayer(MediaPlayerBuilder.create()
                        .media(new Media(path)).build()).build());
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}
}
```

When i run above Code it will show me black window ,how can i solve i?

Comment: What is vid.flv? Is it vp6 encoded? If not, it won't play in JavaFX. Monitor the onError property of your MediaPlayer - was there an error?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem going between Windows 7, Ubuntu and XP runtime environments.  Looks like you're running in Ubuntu.  What version?  In Linux and Windows versions Vista and older, codecs are not included by default.

I'd bet that you don't have the proper codecs required to play the media in question.
Have a look at the following:

Here, scroll down to 'JavaFX Media' at the bottom of the page, and it should help you find what you need.
    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html

Some more helpful (but less technical) info here:
    http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm

A comprehensive matrix of supported video container formats and types is in the:
    [JavaFX 2 Media Package JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html)

Comment: Yep, vp6 encoded flv videos are supposed to work out of the box on all platforms without requiring additional codec installations.  It's likely that the original poster was trying to play an flv video which was not vp6 encoded - in which case they need(ed) to re-encode the video because vp6 is the only codec type that JavaFX 2 supports for flv video.

Comment: That's exactly in line with what I learned.  I had no issues with vp6 flash videos on the other systems, but to get h264 encoded mp4s to work, I had to add the linked-to dependencies.  Thanks for the additional insight.